# Inserting a row to the bottom of a table with predefined text

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Microsoft Word 2010, I have the following macro working quite well in my form.  After the new row is added I need it to have the new row with predefined text added to column 1, 2 and 3.  In Column 2, I need to have multiple lines inside the same row.  The Table has only 3 columns.  How would I do this?

```
Sub addrow()

Dim oTable As Table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oPrevRow As Row, oNewRow As Row
Dim iColumn As Long

' Insert new row
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
Set oPrevRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.count)
oTable.Rows.Add
Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.count)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "need to have multiple lines inside the same row"?

Comment: For example inside a particular cell.  In this case Every row in Column 2.  I need to have a line of text, a blank line, then another line of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.count)
oNewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Column 1 Text"
oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "Column 2 Text"
oNewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = "Column 3 Text"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as expected.  One last question.  For the 2nd Column how do I insert text, then a blank line and then more text on the 3rd line?

Comment: For example inside a particular cell.  In this case Every row in Column 2.  I need to have a line of text, a blank line, then another line of text.

Comment: @ChrisK, might try using vbCrLf.  For example,  .Text = "Foo" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Bar"